# Draw multiple circles on an image in windows.forms using powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am mostly done creating a GUI that will pop up with an image in a picturebox, and allow the user to draw multiple red circles on it by clicking (where I'll then have it save to a passed filepath/name).

User draws the circle by clicking where on the image they want the top left starting point to be, and dragging to resize it (where the previous circle disappears and the correctly sized one is displayed) until they release the mouse.

The first circle appears correctly, but for all following circles it does not refresh properly and thus rather than resizing one circle dragging the mouse displays a bunch of different sized circles corresponding to all the past dragged mouse positions.

I have been banging my head on this one all day, what am I missing that will make the follow-up circles display correctly?

```
$file = "...TestImage.PNG"


$script:DrawingStatus = "In_Progress" #switch case for mouse drag



$panel1 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Panel
$Panel1.AutoScroll = $true;



$win = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$box = New-Object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$box.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($file)
$box.AutoSize = $true




$src = $box.Image



$bmp=new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap $src.width, $src.height
$script:graphics=[System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)
$units = [System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Pixel



$destRect = new-object Drawing.Rectangle 0, 0, $src.width, $src.height
$srcRect = new-object Drawing.Rectangle 0, 0, $src.width, $src.height


$graphics.DrawImage($src, $destRect, $srcRect.X, $srcRect.Y, $srcRect.width, $srcRect.height, $units)

$image = $src 

$Clicky4 = { #Executed on Mouse Drag while mouse is down

param($point)



$graphics.DrawImage($image, $destRect, $srcRect.X, $srcRect.Y, $srcRect.width, $srcRect.height, $units)
$box.image = $bmp


$mouse = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position; 
$point2 = $box.PointToClient($mouse); 
write-host $point; 
$mypen = new-object System.Drawing.Pen black
$mypen.color = "red"
$mypen.width = 3



$graphics.DrawEllipse($mypen, $point.X, $point.Y, ($point2.X-$point.X), ($point2.Y-$point.Y))




}

$clicky2 = { #executed on mouse down, calls clicky4

$script:DrawingStatus = "In_Progress"


write-host "Test 2 Passed!"; 
$mouse = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position; 


$point = $box.PointToClient($mouse); 
write-host $point; 
$box.tag = $point;


$superclick = {

switch ($script:DrawingStatus){

"In_Progress" {


Invoke-Command $clicky4 -ArgumentList $box.tag

}

"Done"{ #does nothing, so dragging mouse with mouse up does not trigger circle resizing

}


}




}

$box.add_MouseMove($superclick)

}



$clicky3 = { #executed on mouse up
write-host "Test 3 Passed!";

$script:DrawingStatus = "Done"



$script:image = $script:BMP #this is my attempt to create a BMP with the drawn circle after resizing so that the box image can be refreshed to this when drawing the next circle

$script:graphics=[System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($script:image)


$mouse = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position; 
$point = $box.PointToClient($mouse); 
write-host $point; 
$array = @(); 
$array += $box.tag; 
$array += $point; 
$win.tag = $array



}





$Panel1.controls.add($box)

$win.width = 1500
$win.height = 800



$panel1.width = ($win.width - 15)

$panel1.height = ($win.height -50)




$box.add_MouseDown($clicky2)
$box.add_MouseUp($clicky3)



$win.Controls.Add($panel1)





$win.ShowDialog()

write-host "Coords: " $win.tag
$initial = $win.tag[0]
$Final = $win.tag[1]


write-host "Initial: " $initial
write-host "Final: " $Final


write-host "X1: " $initial.X
write-host "Y1: " $initial.Y

write-host "X2: " $final.X
write-host "Y2: " $final.Y
```

Comment: Nothing you are doing here is specific to PowerShell. It's Winforms, and you'd have the exact same issues if you were using, VB.net/C# etc. YOu are just using PowerShell as your code-behind, yet, your comment says two different things. Meaning, you say you want to alter an existing circle and create new ones, and there is nothing in your code that shows that you are selecting an existing object/circle to manipulate. Silicon-base life forms (hardware/software) are only compliant. They can only do what they are told to do. What break points did you set/evaluate during execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest reason you're getting multiple circles is because your code is not erasing the old circles. Since you want them to be able to draw multiple circles in the window, the best way to do this would be with two [System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath?view=net-5.0) objects. One with the permanent circles, and one with the temporary circle being resized. MouseUp would add the current temp ellipse to the permanent GraphicsPath, while mouse move would clear and redraw the temp GraphicsPath and call Invalidate. In an Add_Paint event call, you would draw both GraphicsPaths to the ImageBox directly to draw over your base image. When saving after you can draw the permanent Paths onto the image before saving to file to permanently alter them.